When should I use React Native CLI instead of Expo for my project?
I'm starting a new project with React Native and I'm trying to decide between using React Native CLI and Expo. I understand that both have their own advantages and use cases, but I'm not entirely sure which one would be best for my situation. Here are a few details about my project:
Scale: The project will start small but is expected to scale significantly over time.
Complexity: I anticipate needing to integrate a variety of custom native modules and possibly write some native code myself.
Timeline: I need to get a working prototype up and running quickly, but long-term maintainability and performance are crucial.
Team: My team has some experience with JavaScript and React, but limited experience with native development.
Platform: We are targeting both iOS and Android from the start.
i tried expo environment and it's very cool i guess i can't see big differences i just wanted to know what's the scale that i should go for when i need to use CLI instead of expo

For you, it may seem that starting with Expo might be the best way to go first, but eventually switching to the React Native CLI could be beneficial for you the program for as long as possible to get bigger and harder Here's a breakdown of why:
Expo Pro (good for early development):
Faster prototyping: Expo’s tooling and prefabricated components simplify development, giving you a faster working prototype. This fits right in with your need to build quickly at the beginning.
Reduced Setup: Expo handles most of the native configuration under the hood, which is perfect for your team with limited native experience.
Easy cross-platform development: You can develop for both iOS and Android simultaneously in the Expo environment.
Expo Cons (limitations of complex projects):
Limited native modules: As you mentioned, Expo can restrict access to certain native modules. By anticipating the need for custom modules and possible native code, this could be an issue later on.
A few wins: Expo offers less control over build processes and app layout compared to the CLI. This can limit your ability to optimize or tailor the application to specific needs.
Increasing app size: Expo apps are slightly larger due to the included libraries. This can affect performance on low-end devices.
React Native CLI Pros (good for long term):
Full native access: The CLI gives you full control over native libraries and modules, allowing you to integrate any custom functionality you need. This is good for the expected intensity of your project.
Many changes: The CLI provides granular control over build settings and application settings, allowing you to customize performance and customize the app to suit your specific needs for future scaling.
Maybe it’s a little bitstrong text
React Native CLI Pros (good for long term):
Full native access: The CLI gives you full control over native libraries and modules, allowing you to integrate any custom functionality you need. This is good for the expected intensity of your project.
More flexibility: The CLI provides granular control over build configuration and application configuration, so you can customize performance and tailor the application to your specific needs for future scaling.
Potentially smaller app size: With more control over the included libraries, you can build a simpler app.
When you should consider changing the CLI:
Creating Expo Limits: If you need non-Expo capabilities or your app's performance suffers from size limits, it may be time to move to the CLI
Increased team proficiency : As your team gains more experience in native development, they will be better equipped to handle the challenges of the CLI.
